# Row binding two sql tables without duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i bind the following two tables in sql together so that the duplicates are not kept in the resulting table:

Table 1 is:

```
Table 1 
-------
Col_1 | Col_2 |Stuff | Month 
---------------------------
1        a      qwe    May   
2        b      sdf    May 
3        c      ert    May
4        d      pol    May
5        e      lop    May
```

Here is Table 2

```
Table 2 
-------
Col_1 | Col_2 | Stuff | Month 
-----------------------------
4       d        pol    May
5       e        lop    May
7       f        ghb    June
8       g        fes    June
9       h        lkl    June
```

I want to make the following table - call it table 3 - this table takes table 1 and adds the rows that are not duplicated in table 2 to it (this can be either at the top or at the bottom)

table 3 - what i want to acheve looks like this:

```
Table 3 
-------
Col_1 | Col_2 |Stuff | Month 
---------------------------
1        a      qwe    May   
2        b      sdf    May 
3        c      ert    May
4        d      pol    May
5        e      lop    May 
7       f        ghb    June
8       g        fes    June
9       h        lkl    June
```

How can i do this in SQL? I'm using Micrsofot SQL Server Management studio 2017

any help appreciated

The columns always stay the same

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. Look for `NOT IN`, `UNION` or `EXCEPT`

Comment: Users gave me answers below - i'll try those

Comment: And what if only some of the values are the same, such as duplicates for "2" but other columns are different.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply looking for `UNION` operator which removes duplicates from two identical queries (having the same column count and data types):

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, stuff, month FROM table_1
UNION
SELECT col_1, col_2, stuff, month FROM table_2
ORDER BY col_1
```

Applied sorting based on your sample result.

If you need to materialize your output (store it in a table) you could look into using `SELECT ... INTO` clause for this like below:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, stuff, month FROM table_1
INTO table_3
UNION
SELECT col_1, col_2, stuff, month FROM table_2
ORDER BY col_1
```

The `INTO` part is just needed after the first select statement and there's no need for a derived table (subquery) for this to work.

Now, while that's possible, I'd still opt for the same output with clearer intent for the future reader and make use of a derived table like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO table_3
FROM (
  SELECT col_1, col_2, stuff, month FROM table_1
  UNION
  SELECT col_1, col_2, stuff, month FROM table_2
  ORDER BY col_1
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select * into table3 from
(
select * from table1
union 
select * from table2
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

> Select *  from table1 
>   Union
>   Select * from table2